# Why is it necessary to break symmetry to get magnetoelectric effect in multiferroics?

Tags: electromagnetism, experimental-physics, magnetic-moment

Spatial or time symmetry needs to be broken for both magnetic and electric to happen in the same material. But how is symmetry hindering the process?